# CSS - submit buttons displayed shorter than text inputs

Tags: css, forms, input

My CSS is as follows:

```
input,textarea
{
    font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color:#779EC0;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-top:10px;
    border: solid 1px #85b1de;
    background-color: #EDF2F7;
    width:100%;
}
```

I am trying to output both a text input and a submit input.
The submit input however appears a few pixels shorter than the text inputs.. for apparently no reason.

I have googled this with no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, the answer is hidden in the default style sheets in modern browsers.  The issue pertains to the box model of CSS.

Basically, input[type="text"], textarea, generally most other elements have a standard box sizing mode ('content-box').  input[type="submit"] uses the border-box sizing mode, which is used by fewer elements.

Add this line of css to your above style declaration:

```
 box-sizing:content-box;
```

This will override the browser stylesheet defaults and set all of these elements to content-box, which will fix your sizing issue.

---

I added a fiddle and realized that Firefox still needs the -moz prefix:

```
 box-sizing:content-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:content-box;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vXFDN/2/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
 input[type=submit] {
  //your style for button type submit
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because the textarea can have a scroll bar, and different browsers interpret this differently.

I would recommend simply fixing your textarea with a seperate width:

```
input,textarea
{
    font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color:#779EC0;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-top:10px;
    border: solid 1px #85b1de;
    background-color: #EDF2F7;
    width:100%;
}

textarea
{
    width:98%;
}
```

See fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/VJTMF/1/